# How to test whether or not a cell has passed data validation?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been looking through the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation) for the **DataValidation** class and have not found a way to check whether an individual cell has passed it's data validation test.  I can see in the sheet that it is either valid or invalid, but how can my script *see* that information?

Perhaps something like `activeCell.DataValidation.isValid()` would return true or false? Does anyone know a Google built-in method or have one of their own to accomplish this?

On input, the validation checks if the value matches something in, say, column B. Ultimately, the user input should be added to column B if confirmed by the user.

Comment: Can you post what your validation is? Maybe this can be easily tested with a simple script or compared with getCriteriaValues() array

Comment: @utphx Thank you. I edited just now.. Basically it just searches for a match in another column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I just found out that there is no way to check if a cell is valid in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713365/google-apps-script-how-to-tell-if-a-cell-value-has-passed-validation?rq=1) (that I somehow missed when searching for this answer).

The official request to Google is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=4655). Please go comment and star for this useful method to be added to Google Apps Script!